# Subsets of $\{1,\cdots,n\}$ with max intersection $2$.

Tags: combinatorics

Consider a collection of $n$ different $8$-element subsets of $\{1,\cdots,n\}$. 
If for any $2$ subsets in our collection we have that the size of the intersection is no larger than $2$ we say that the collection is "good".

Given $n$, how many good collections are there?